# getting no such element exception message

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

i am using eclipse juno and testing the application actitime,which has a check box in login page "keepLoggedInCheckBox"

The HTML source of it,

```
<input type="checkbox" title="Do not select if this computer is shared" 
id="keepLoggedInCheckBox" value="on" name="remember">
```

I am trying locate the check box "keepLoggedInCheckBox" by using ,

```
WebElement check = driver.findElement(By.id("keepLoggedInCheckBox"));
```

But getting this error,

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"keepLoggedInCheckBox"}

i tried with xpath (//input[@id='keepLoggedInCheckBox']) ,also getting same error.

please help me, to solve this.

Comment: Is it possible the element is not on the page before you try to locate it? Have you tried waiting for a few seconds then checking? You can simply use sleep for testing purposes but the robust way to do it is to use WebDriverWait, assuming this is the issue.

Comment: 1. Providing the URL of the web-page that you are trying to access might help us providing you with a better answer. 2. Is it possible that the element that you are trying to locate is inside an `iframe`?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. The DOM looses the reference to the element in question. It can either be **StaleStateReferenceException** or **NoSuchElementException**. There are two ways to deal with the situation. 
(Though my solution is in Java. The underlying concept is the same. )

By using the the following method, you can try clicking an element. If exception is thrown then catch the exception and try to click again until the element is present:

```
public boolean retryingFindClick(By by) {
    boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            WebElement userClick = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
            action.moveToElement(userClick).click().build().perform();
            driver.findElement(by).click();
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("StaleElementReferenceException");
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("No Such Element Found");
        }
        attempts++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have added implicitlyWait which will allow your DOM content to load.
Note: Please replace Your URL with the exact URL.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("Your URL");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='keepLoggedInCheckBox']")).click();
```